# Dataframe test two conditions

Tags: python, pandas

For this dataframe
df

```
   basketID  productCode
0         1           23
1         1           24
2         1           25
3         2           23
4         3           23
5         4           25
6         5           24
7         5           25
```

Gives as expected

```
(df['productCode']) == 23
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
```

But if I want both 23 and 1

```
(df['productCode']) == 23 & (df['basketID'] == 1)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
```

Everything is false.
Why first line was not recognized?

Comment: `(df['productCode'] == 23) | (df['basketID'] == 1)` perhaps?

Comment: Note that your first closing parenthesis is in the wrong spot in the last case, whether with an and or or combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `)` after `23` because operator precedence:

```
(df['productCode'] == 23) & (df['basketID'] == 1)
```